# Support for cores revision ox17 and ox18 disabled by module param allsupport=0. Try b43 allsupport =1

Tags: updates, 14.10, b43

Why do i get a black screen on boot (after installing the latest ubuntu 14.10 updates) with the following message.

[ 16.697414] Support for cores revision ox17 and ox18 disabled by module param allsupport=0. Try b43 allsupport =1

I can boot ok with the previous kernel

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd one - I found a post in an [Arch Linux forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/b43-wireless-driver-error) indicating that this could be loaded with modprobe

If you cannot get your system to boot fully you will need to boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) (terminal mode), mount your drive with RW permissions, and create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf`

The contents of the file should be

```
# Activate experimental support for some hardware revisions
options b43 allhwsupport=1
```

Following this you will need to reboot.

If you can get into your system, then you still need to create the file as above, but you could force the module to reload with `sudo rmmod b43 && sudo modprobe b43`