# Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0

Tags: boot, error-handling, multi-core

I was wondering if there is a fix for this problem, as every time I boot my laptop this message comes up. Is there any way to get rid if it? Thanks.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/b43-wireless-driver-error By the way: your message is missing part of the error. There should be a mentioning something like "Try b43.allhwsupport=1" behind it. Please confirm if that is the case; otherwise you might need another option set.

Comment: First you need to tell us your hardware, version of Ubuntu, and kernel. Then you should post the entire message. Is everything working ? Is this an error or a warning ? Not sure from what little you posted if this is your problem - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214439

Comment: This seems to be an up-and coming problem - I answered the same as @Rinzwind yesterday [at this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/549409/black-screen-on-boot-after-installing-the-latest-ubuntu-14-10-updates/549415#549415)

Comment: @CharlesGreen ah I missed that so: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/549409/black-screen-on-boot-after-installing-the-latest-ubuntu-14-10-updates/549415#549415

Comment: @Rinzwind  Slightly different title, I'm afraid.